# Problems with encoding while installing python package kahypar

Tags: python, installation, pip, package

I'm trying to install the python package  kahypar https://pypi.org/project/kahypar/

However, during the installation procedure which I start with "pip install kahypar" I get the following error message:

```
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\bart_\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-t12wftnf\kahypar_e4663c08fc5b4ad7a876559842486c35\setup.py", line 71, in <module>    
          long_description = fh.read()
                             ^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\bart_\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 5786: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed
```

Online I've found that this problem might originate from a type of encoding used in the python environment that should be set to UTF-8 by having `export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8` in the environment activation script.
Sadly, this error keeps popping up and I'm really out of ideas how to install the Kahypar package in my Python environment.

Comment: https://github.com/kahypar/kahypar/blob/acb75888f02aa4320b43c2a558c33de51be0301e/setup.py#L77 seems to be doing the right thing; are you using an older version where it doesn't use the explicit `encoding` keyword, perhaps?

Comment: @tripleee As i'm just installing the kahypar package using pip install kahypar, I think that the newest version gets downloaded before pip tries to install it. I've checked and only version 1.0 seems to be available through pip, but on the website https://pypi.org/project/kahypar/ they already state that it should be version 1.3.4 somehow

Comment: Are you on a really old version of Python, or a really old version of Pip? You could always try to download from the Github URL (modern `pip` should easily allow that too).

Comment: https://github.com/kahypar/kahypar/commit/d0f08ebaad1f60db9006d25b5bc4cce837464fcc seems to be the fix for this particular error but who knows what else they have fixed since version 1.0. (Also, you don't need `codecs` for this; it's a Python 2-ism.)

Comment: i'm on a freshly installed version of python 3.11.5, installing directly from git gives a different error message. I'll try and sort this one out and look up if I can find some direction already online, I'll update if I find something